# how to calculate inverse tan?

Tags: iphone, math

I am using `UIAcceleration` for rotation. I have opposite side, adjacent side, but I want to calculate tan-1(y/x) inverse tan.

Comment: difference between atan() and atan2()

Comment: I don't get what you have, do you have only two catheti? Can you provide a pic or a better description?

Answer (score 9):

Always use atan2(y,x) instead of atan(y/x), for two reasons. One is mentioned by David Maymudes (problems with x=0). The other is that atan2() deals with the full range from -π to +π, whereas atan() only gives you an output between -π/2 and +π/2, and cannot distinguish between (x,y)=(2,2) and (x,y)=(-2,-2) since you lose the sign information when you do the division and pass only the quotient y/x into atan().

Comment: Note that in most atan2 functions, Y is the first parameter, not X

Comment: i got lazy and followed the other 2 answ w/o looking it up. thanks for the prod. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The standard C math.h functions are available:

```
#include <math.h>

...
float theta = atan2f(y, x);
...
```

Comment: Note that in most atan2 functions, Y is the first parameter, not X

Answer (score 3):

`atan2(y, x)` is the same thing as `atan(y/x)`, but it can deal properly with the case where `x = 0` (i.e. a vertical line going up or down) without having do deal with positive vs. negative infinity.

Comment: Note that in most atan2 functions, Y is the first parameter, not X

Comment: False: atan2 will return an oriented angle (between 0 and 2 Pi, or -Pi and Pi), whereas atan(y / x) will return a number between -Pi/2 and Pi/2